# How to encode input values in json using java

Tags: java, android, json

I have some input values like this:

```
customername
    phone 
    email
    .....
     some items values
     itemname1
     itemname2
     ........
```

In every item name have some unitprice
         quantity
         ........

I'm trying to encode these values in json like this:

```
{
"info": {
    "customername": "abc",
    "phone": "123",
    "email": "an@gmail.com",

},
"item": {
    "itemname1": {
        "unitprice": "100",
        "qty": "3",

    },
    "itemname2": {
        "unitprice": "500",
        "qty": "2",

    }
}
}
```

I 'm unable to encode all value like above.

here is my code:

```
 private void jsonEncoding() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();


        try {
            obj1.put("name", name);
            obj1.put("email", email);
            obj1.put("phone", phone);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        obj.put("info",obj1 );
        System.out.print(obj);

        System.out.print(obj1);
    }
```

How to encode values like above json format.

Comment: Yes you can. Using Gson. Have a look on https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: Yes @Abhishek...

Comment: I think you are making a mistake here by making "item" property an object and making itemname1, itemname2 etc as properties. Things are going to be a lot simpler for you if you just make your "item" property a JsonArray or JsonObjects and itemname as property inside those JsonObjects. Example: 
`{  
        "name":"itemname1",
        "unitprice": "500",
        "qty": "2"

    }`

Comment: I know that @rineez.. my web developer gave me this format ..I'm bound to encode this format.

Comment: Ah! I know how that feels. @Neo Do you know any kind of martial arts? or wrestling?

Comment: lol @rineez.....

Comment: yes ,your answer is very helpful for me..@Abhishek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in 2 ways:

1. Using 3rd party libraries like `Gson/Jackson` for converting the POJO class data to `json object string` (use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for creating POJO class easily)
2. Manually do JsonParsing like below:

> ```
> try {
> // info node
> JSONObject objInfo = new JSONObject();
> objInfo.put("name", name);
> objInfo.put("email", email);
> objInfo.put("phone", phone);
>
> // itemname1 node
> JSONObject itemname1 = new JSONObject();
> itemname1.put("unitprice", unitprice1);
> itemname1.put("qty", qty1);
>
> // itemname2 node
> JSONObject itemname2 = new JSONObject();
> itemname2.put("unitprice", unitprice2);
> itemname2.put("qty", qty2);
>
> // item node
> JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
>
> // adding itemname1 & itemname2 to item
> item.put("itemname1",itemname1);
> item.put("itemname2",itemname2);
>
> // root node
> JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
> root.put("info",objInfo);
> root.put("item",item);
>
> System.out.print(root);
>
> } catch(JsonException e){
>      e.printStackTrace();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Create a `POJO` class similar to your response

```
class Info {
  String customerName;
  String phone;
   String email;
}
class ItemName{
  String unitprice;
  String qty;
}

class Item{
   ItemName itemname1;
   ItemName itemname2;
}

class Data{
    Info info;
    Item item;
}
```

Now just use google `gson` library to convert instance of `Data` to `json` as in

```
new Gson().toJson(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it may help**

> You need to create three classes and as your using Gson means you are going with networking feature hence implement serializable for all like below.

```
  class CustomObject implements Serializable {

      Info info;

      Map<String, ItemName> item;

      public CustomObject() {
          this(null, null);
      }

      public CustomObject(Info info, Map<String, ItemName> item) {
          this.info = info;
          this.item = item;
      }

      public Info getInfo() {
          return info;
      }

      public void setInfo(Info info) {
          this.info = info;
      }

      public Map<String, ItemName> getItem() {
          return item;
      }

      public void setItem(Map<String, ItemName> item) {
          this.item = item;
      }
  }

  class Info implements Serializable {

      String customername;
      String phone;
      String email;

      public Info() {
          this("","","");
      }

      public Info(String customername, String phone, String email) {
          this.customername = customername;
          this.phone = phone;
          this.email = email;
      }

      public String getCustomername() {
          return customername;
      }

      public void setCustomername(String customername) {
          this.customername = customername;
      }

      public String getPhone() {
          return phone;
      }

      public void setPhone(String phone) {
          this.phone = phone;
      }

      public String getEmail() {
          return email;
      }

      public void setEmail(String email) {
          this.email = email;
      }
  }



  class ItemName implements Serializable {

      String unitprice;
      String qty;

      public ItemName() {
          this("", "");
      }

      public ItemName(String unitprice, String qty) {
          this.unitprice = unitprice;
          this.qty = qty;
      }

      public String getUnitprice() {
          return unitprice;
      }

      public void setUnitprice(String unitprice) {
          this.unitprice = unitprice;
      }

      public String getQty() {
          return qty;
      }

      public void setQty(String qty) {
          this.qty = qty;
      }
      }
```

> Now You Have to add your data as per need like below.

```
    CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject();

    Info info = new Info();

    info.setCustomername("abc");
    info.setPhone("123");
    info.setEmail("an@gmail.com");

    customObject.setInfo(info);

    ItemName itemname1 = new ItemName();

    itemname1.setUnitprice("100");
    itemname1.setQty("3");

    ItemName itemname2 = new ItemName();

    itemname2.setUnitprice("500");
    itemname2.setQty("2");

    Map<String, ItemName> item = new HashMap<>();

    item.put("itemname1", itemname1);
    item.put("itemname2", itemname2);

    customObject.setItem(item);

    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(customObject));
```

> Above System.out.println gives output as

```
    {
      "info":
         {
             "customername":"abc",
             "phone":"123",
             "email":"an@gmail.com"},
       "item":{
             "itemname1":
                         {
                           "unitprice":"100",
                           "qty":"3"
                         },
             "itemname2":
                         {
                           "unitprice":"500",
                           "qty":"2"
                          }
             }
     }
```

> Now how to parse your string which you got from server or any source to that CustomObject class. Its very simple through Gson library by google.

```
     String str = "{\n" +
            "        \"info\":\n" +
            "                {\n" +
            "                    \"customername\":\"abc\",\n" +
            "                    \"phone\":\"123\",\n" +
            "                    \"email\":\"an@gmail.com\"\n" +
            "                },\n" +
            "        \"item\": \n" +
            "                {\n" +
            "                    \"itemname1\":\n" +
            "                    {\n" +
            "                        \"unitprice\":\"100\",\n" +
            "                        \"qty\":\"3\"\n" +
            "                    },\n" +
            "                    \"itemname2\":\n" +
            "                    {\n" +
            "                        \"unitprice\":\"500\",\n" +
            "                        \"qty\":\"2\"\n" +
            "                    }\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "    }";

       CustomObject customObject = new Gson().fromJson(str, new TypeToken<CustomObject>(){}.getType());

       System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(customObject));
```